# Numbered list resets after code block

Tags: discussion, list

## Context

1. I often try to write up my answers in a list of actions, to organize it.
2. Then I usually put some `Code` that he needs to place or modify :

> (Four space for Stack Overflow, ">" does the same effet here) **Code here**

3. Then continue to write the list of.... Wait, why is there a number **1** to the left?

## Question

Why does the list reset after the Code block?

Comment: All you need is a one single space before ordinary text, or four spaces before code block, to make it part of the list item.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh... I see. Thanks. But the starting number problem remains. We can't decide explicitly what the numbers are. Why implement this *feature* in the first place?

Comment: It's useful for lazy people and greatly helps if you want to change position of one item. You can have them all start with `1.` yet the order remains.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for answering my question, I'll edit my question to make it clearer for other people finding this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No need for such a thing
2. Because it is very easy to

   > add stuff while still keeping it inside the list

   ```
    Yes, even code.
   ```
3. See? List is not broken.

Source code for the above:

```
1. No need for such a thing
2. Because it is very easy to

 >add stuff while still keeping it inside the list

        Yes, even code.

3. See? List is not broken.
```

(note the single space before the ">add..." and four spaces in addition to existing four spaces of code)

Comment: Why did my list break then?

Comment: @Sifu because you did not have any space so the markdown thought the list is finished.

Comment: *".. so the markdown thought the list is finished"*. This is the key component here.

Comment: @Niek true, that's why we can add extra spaces to tell the markdown "no, list isn't finished just yet"